# Can Not Update/Upgrade After Unregistered 2 versions' Ubuntu and Installed one Ubuntu as WSL

Tags: upgrade, updates, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Had successfully update and upgrade Ubuntu on WSL succesfully:

[image]

then I unregistered the 2 version of Ubuntu and installed one Ubuntu.
Got following errors:

[image]

Tried  `~$ grep -nvr "^#" /etc/apt/ | grep impish`, and got the following info:

```
grep: /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntu-keyring-2012-cdimage.gpg: binary file matches

grep: /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntu-keyring-2018-archive.gpg: binary file matches
```

Anyone could give hints? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I know the reason "the firewall blocks the DNS name resolution on the Linux subsystem" and the problem is solved